# 2 dimensional random values array with 2 user entered values from asp.net web form textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. prepare a form which accepts 2 numeric positive nos.  On clicking generate button, a 2 dimension array of 10 x 10 size will completely filled up with random numbers between those 2 user inputted numbers.

You will print the entire matrix on screen in 10 rows by 10 cols using a function.

There will be one more button called transpose.  When user clicks on this button, entire matrix will be transposed. i.e. the all the data elements in rows will be interchanged with columns. After transpose, it will get printed below again.  Both print should be visible to users.

```
    public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intLL = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        int intUL = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
        int[,] arr = new int[size, size];
        for (int row =0; row < size;row++)
        {
            for(int col=0;col<size;col++)
            {
                arr[row, col] = r.Next(intLL,intUL);
                //Response.Output.Write(arr[row,col]+TextBox1.Text+TextBox2.Text+" ");
                Response.Output.Write(arr[row, col] + "  ");
            }
            Response.Write(" </br>");
        }
    }

    public void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i get the answer how to generate matrix with random values but on button_2 click event how i get transpose of matrix to display it on same screen

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We know what your task is, but we have no idea what your actual problem is when you tried to do that task. Feel free to check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and the awesome [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what do you mean by merge 2 user inputted? what are contents of these two textboxes?

Comment: @osmanRahimi I think OP meant reading what the user did input and using those values in their code, but que question is a bit un clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are hardcoding the minimun and maximun values of your [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) call.

Just check what the user entered in the textboxes and use that values instead. After doing that you could do your traspoosing logic.

Something similar to:

```cs
int minValue = 0;
int maxValue = 0;

if (!Int.TryParse(tbMinimunValue, out minValue) || !Int.TryParse(tbMaximunValue, out maxValue))
{
    Response.Write("Please enter numbers");
    return;
}

// TODO: Add aditional checks like checking min < max, and min and max are positive values

Random r = new Random();
int size = 10;
int[,] arr = new int[size, size];
for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        arr[i, j] = r.Next(minValue, maxValue);
        Response.Output.Write(arr[i,j]+" ");
    }
    Response.Write(" </br>");
}
```

Comment: please help me for button 2